# A little Game/Quiz: Do you see my values? (Interpreting Hex-Values)

Tags: bluetooth, hex, scale

Okay I need some Help... I got a bluetooth-le-weight-scale. I can connect my Raspberry Pi to this scale and get some data. But its not easy for me to read my values in this hex-salad.

After every measurement I get two lines of Information, which should contain my values

*(I simulated all measurements ... Person 5 is just me pushing my hands on the scale .. Person 2 + 3 is me wearing socks on the scale, so no need to give me some medical advices if you find some unrealistic values :D )*

Scale: starts with 5.0kg(officaly, but i can see a 4.9 as starting point), Max 180kg (this could be just a safety note. its a glass-scale), d = 100g

what I noted from the Display:

```
#  | Person | m kg| Fat % | TbW % | Mus % | Bone kg | kcal | BMI
1  |   5    |13,3 |   5   |  72,7 |  60,1 |   0,8   | 1056 | 13,3
2  |   3    |73,6 |  26,3 |  51,1 |  34,2 |   3,5   | 2428 | 24,3
3  |   2    |76,8 |  18,5 |  61,1 |  41,9 |   3,4   | 2741 | 24,8
4  |   5    |15,0 |   5   |  70,3 |  58,4 |   0,9   | 1092 | 15,0
5  |   6    | 5,1 |   5   |  73   |  66,5 |   0,5   | 881  | 5,1
```

What I received via Bluetooth:

```
# | handle | Byte   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | 0x001b | value: 1d 32 05 00 fe 0f 13 11 11 01 12 00 ff 05 09 00 00 00 00  
1 | 0x001e | value: 6f 0f 13 11 11 05 20 04 32 f0 d7 f2 59 f2 08 f0 00 00 00 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 | 0x001b | value: 1d c0 1c 00 fe 45 06 00 00 7a 13 00 ff 03 09 00 00 00 00  
2 | 0x001e | value: 6f 45 06 00 00 03 7c 09 07 f1 ff f1 56 f1 23 f0 00 00 00 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
3 | 0x001b | value: 1d 00 1e 00 fe 37 01 00 00 d7 12 00 ff 02 09 00 00 00 00  
3 | 0x001e | value: 6f 37 01 00 00 02 b5 0a b9 f0 63 f2 a3 f1 22 f0 00 00 00 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
4 | 0x001b | value: 1d dc 05 00 fe 80 14 11 11 83 18 00 ff 05 09 00 00 00 00  
4 | 0x001e | value: 6f 80 14 11 11 05 44 04 32 f0 bf f2 48 f2 09 f0 00 00 00 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
5 | 0x001b | value: 1d fe 01 00 fe 5c 15 11 11 ac 16 00 ff 06 09 00 00 00 00   
5 | 0x001e | value: 6f 5c 15 11 11 06 71 03 32 f0 da f2 99 f2 05 f0 00 00 00
```

Note:
Each time before receiving the values, I have to send my scale a Unix-timestamp.. most of the times, I had just send 1111111111 or 0000000000 or something like that.. but I did not note what I send.. sorry..

there is always another incoming line where I spotted the user values, that are stored in the scale. So I think these are unimportant but maybe I'm wrong

> P2, male, Height: 176cm, Age: 34
>
> P3, female, Height: 174cm, Age: 23
>
> P5, male, Height: 100cm, Age: 10

so maybe someone could tell me, like where I can find the Information that represents my weight. I just have spotted the person numbers

thanks for helping & greetings from germany

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok ok.. I solved it...

**0x1b:**

weight: byte: 1 & 2

timestamp: byte 5-8

person: byte 13

**0x1e:**

timestamp: byte 1-4

person: 5

kcal: 6 & 7

fat: 8 & 9

tbw: 10 & 11

muscle: 12 & 13

bone: 14 & 15

Answer (score 2):

To add some more details:
values decode as unsigned integers, little endian. For some obscure reason the 2 byte (short) integers have a most significant nibble as 0xf.
Transmission starts off with indication 0x25 which contains the programmed properties of the person detected (i.e. weight is within +/- 2 kg of last measurement).

```
0x25:
person: byte 2
gender: byte 4 (1=male, 2=female)
age: byte 5
size: byte 6
activity: byte 8 (0=normal, 3=high)
```

Comment: and I think 

    gender: byte 4  (3 = male.athletic, 4 = female.athletic) 
but not sure at this point. But its something like that

Comment: gender is byte 4, athletic is what i called 'activity' above. Byte 8 shows 0x03 when athletic is selected. Python code to communicate and evaluate on a Raspberry now fully operational thanks to your kickstarter!

Comment: :) are you going to publish your complete code somewhere?

Comment: find the work in progress in https://github.com/keptenkurk/BS440 Next will be filling a database and graphing the contents...