# BTSNOOP_HCI.log file with Wireshark

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to extract data from my [BLE watch][1], similar to the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271217/solved-connecting-to-a-bluetooth-smart-le-weight-scale-with-bluez-bluetoothctl-g/43505062#43505062) & [here][3] for the weighing scale.

When I open the bluetooth log "btsnoop_hci.log" using wireshark, I am not sure if the log is right - as there are many unknown packets. Does the wireshark require to be configured the correct way? As mentioned in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271217/solved-connecting-to-a-bluetooth-smart-le-weight-scale-with-bluez-bluetoothctl-g/43505062#43505062) (in the Solved part - copying/pasting here)

> Okay.. I solved this by my self.. all I needed to do was change ,,**char-
>   write-cmd" to ,,char-write-req"**.. In the log-file by my Android-Hci-Snoop >it was always a write requst. Don't know why I didn't recognize it all >the time...

I should have seen a few char-write-cmd and char-write-req messages in the hci log which I have captured between the watch and my android phone. But I don't see any of these messages.

I have attached my "btsnoop_hci.log" file([download from here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_0y7SuWYqH1akw1aURZUHd5QXc)), if someone could confirm using Wireshark(or other means) that the log file is OK or if I missed spotting these messages (char-write-cmd, char-write-req) or if I need to do some additional configuration with wireshark  --- it will be of supreme help in carrying on with my work.

Understandably the above links are for weighing scale, but I am trying with a smart-watch - but these messages that I refer should be in the log else the watch would function, which it does with my android phone. So, spotting these messages/understanding what is wrong with my btsnoop_hci.log file is very important.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is resolved now.

The problem was the wireshark version - I was using version 1.6.x, I changed it to 1.12.1 and I am able to see a whole lot of new information including 'write-req, write-cmd, etc' messages.